# How to include a lambda function version in the target group resource in a cloudformation script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm trying to create a target group resource having a lambda as the target through a CFT (serverless.yaml). Since I'm going to use SnapStart in Lambda I need to specify a version of the Lambda function when creating the target group. As per the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-targetdescription.html#cfn-elasticloadbalancingv2-targetgroup-targetdescription-id), an ARN of the lambda function can be given as 'Id'. But once I pass the ARN from the function version, it gives the following error,

> Resource handler returned message: "elasticloadbalancing principal does not have permission to invoke arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:336381469992:function:my-api-v1-dev-handler:13 from target group arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:us-east-1:targetgroup/my-apis-v1-dev/f811183d66a6a480 (Service: ElasticLoadBalancingV2, Status Code: 403, Request ID: ee4741b2-bd5e-4d61-aa22-601d0232c670)"

I have defined the following resources in the serverless.yaml,

```
 HandlerLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    SnapStart:
      ApplyOn: PublishedVersions

lambdaInvokePermission:
  Type: "AWS::Lambda::Permission"
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !Ref HandlerLambdaFunction
    Action: "lambda:InvokeFunction"
    Principal: "elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com"
    SourceArn: !Ref targetGroup

functionVersion:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Version
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !GetAtt [ HandlerLambdaFunction, Arn ]

targetGroup:
  Type: "AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup"
  Properties:
    Name: b2b-customer-apis-${self:provider.stage}
    TargetType: "lambda"
    TargetGroupAttributes:
      - Key: lambda.multi_value_headers.enabled
        Value: true
    Targets:
      - Id: !Ref functionVersion
```

What would be the cause for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As per the information from AWS support team, this is an internal issue known to them and they are working on a fix.

As a workaround the function version resource was removed from the serverless file and used the dedicated serverless field to create a version per each deployment.

> versionFunctions: true

Also function version reference in the target group resource was replaced with the Lambda function resource, requiring the target group resource to be updated manually by setting the latest function version through AWS console.

```
 HandlerLambdaFunction:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
  Properties:
    SnapStart:
      ApplyOn: PublishedVersions

lambdaInvokePermission:
  Type: AWS::Lambda::Permission
  Properties:
    FunctionName: !Ref HandlerLambdaFunction
    Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
    Principal: elasticloadbalancing.amazonaws.com

targetGroup:
  DependsOn: lambdaInvokePermission
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
  Properties:
    Name: b2b-customer-apis-${self:provider.stage}
    TargetType: lambda
    TargetGroupAttributes:
      - Key: lambda.multi_value_headers.enabled
        Value: true
    Targets:
      - Id: !GetAtt [ HandlerLambdaFunction, Arn ]
```